# Thumbnail can't be customized

Tags: facebook, facebook-like, sharing

Here is the website in question: http://photobybrent.com/

The FB "Like" link in the grey header-area is the issue. When people click "like," the wrong thumbnail is shown, of an AD. Not good! In fact, I took the ad image off the site all together and it's STILL showing.

I've used the following code in the head of my document and the "Like" thumbnail is still showing an ad on people's profiles:

```
<meta property="og:image" content="http://photobybrent.com/wp-content/themes/brentstanley/images/fb_thumb.jpg" />
<link rel="image_src" type="image/jpeg" href="http://photobybrent.com/wp-content/themes/brentstanley/images/fb_thumb.jpg" />
```

Any insight or suggestion is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You should address the problem reported by the Facebook Object Debugger before anything else.

http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Fphotobybrent.com%2F